# Document metadata search functionality on salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement for documents available on salesforce that the documents can be retrieved through metadata searches. Please can you advise how this would work practically.

Also for historical documents they will be stored on SharePoint, with document links available in Salesforce. For this approach can the document metadata be migrated to Salesforce?